# Finding consecutive number in column and printing selective value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate consecutive numbers from colA and then select the middle number from consecutive seqeunce to print out value corresponding to it in column Freq1

[image]

this code is not printing any value
for col in df.ColA:
if col == col + 1 and col + 1 == col + 2:
print(col)
can anyone suggest any idea

```
ColA Freq1
 4     0
 5    100
 6    200
 18    5
 19    600
 20    700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the resulting rows you are looking for:

Basically where `ColA` is equal to the previous row + 1 and the next row - 1

**This of course operates under the assumption that there are always only 3 consecutive numbers.**

```
df.loc[(df['ColA'].eq(df['ColA'].shift(1).add(1))) & (df['ColA'].eq(df['ColA'].shift(-1).sub(1)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `groupby` to identify the stretches of contiguous values, then size of the groups and the middle value:

```
# find consecutive values
group = df['ColA'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()

# make grouper
g = df.groupby(group)['ColA']

# get index of row in group
# compare to group size to find mid-point
m = g.cumcount().eq(g.transform('size').floordiv(2))

# perform boolean indexing
out = df.loc[m]
```

output:

```
   ColA  Freq1
1     5    100
4    19    600
```

intermediates:

```
   ColA  Freq1  diff  group  cumcount  size  size//2      m
0     4      0   NaN      1         0     3        1  False
1     5    100   1.0      1         1     3        1   True
2     6    200   1.0      1         2     3        1  False
3    18      5  12.0      2         0     3        1  False
4    19    600   1.0      2         1     3        1   True
5    20    700   1.0      2         2     3        1  False
```

Comment: this code is printing only ColA values but not corresponding values of Freq1

Comment: @SagorikaNath this is not true, have a closer look and give it a try. You have to `print(out)` to print the result